# Screen Overlay in unity Builds

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After I built the project using `"Gradle"`, When run the Project, the applications I had previously opened on my phone are visible on the UI.

I have not written any specific scripts about this problem and this problem occurs on all Android devices.

[applications I had previously opened on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucwmh.png)

[Take a look at top of screen Under Text "V10 Spyder" there is spot and back of the screen is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXyPP.jpg)

[This is an empty scene and the problem remains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEjkk.png)

**Note :** I upgraded Unity to 2018.4 but there is still the same problem

**Edit:** This error occurs when building with "internal"

```
 Failed to re-package resources with the following parameters:
package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/We Call this SDK/android-sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: You will need to provide more details like scripts/assets/plugins you are using in you projects. Also if you cannot build, post the log.

Comment: Please read the full text. I didn't use any scripts.